# Make won't rebuild files changed with hg pull

Tags: linux, mercurial, makefile

I've used `hg pull` and `hg update` to pull some new revisions to my Ubuntu box and update my local source to the new head. There's no branching involved here. I confirmed that they were changed to the latest revision by checking a change that I made five minutes ago on Windows and it's right here, and the latest modified time on the file is clearly three minutes ago (the last build was 18 days ago).

But when I run `make`, it seems to think nothing has changed. I used make clean also but nothing happened. I even deleted the build output and intermediate object file directories, to no effect.

How can I make `make` recognize that my files have changed and rebuild them?

Comment: That's hard to answer without more details about your `Makefile`.

Comment: I didn't realize it had any say on the matter.

Comment: The rules in the `Makefile` determine what gets updated when.  But see this hg FAQ: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.Why_is_the_modification_time_of_files_not_restored_on_checkout.3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was using Debug64 as my config instead of debug64. Apparently `make` doesn't mention it when you try to build absolutely nothing at all, since that config does not exist.